# Can predicate values have wildcards in Mountebank?

Tags: integration-testing, mountebank

I am trying to define a stub:

```
{
   "predicates":[
      {
         "equals":{
            "method":"GET",
            "path":"/sword/eBISXMLInvoice2.do",
            "query": {
              "action": "index",
              "page": 3 <-- this one!
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "responses":[
      {
         "is":{
            "statusCode":200,
            "headers":{
               "Content-Type":"application/xml"
            },
            "body":"<doclist><document uuid='101654' type='invoice' date='2018-11-14 13:49:43' /></doclist>"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

One of the expected query string parameters (called "page") can have multiple values. How can I define the predicate to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is actually very easy to answer. According to the [docs](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/predicates), the "equals" predicate, *will match if any value matches*.

Full text:

> On occasion you may encounter multi-valued keys. This can be the case
>   with querystrings and HTTP headers that have repeating keys, for
>   example `?key=first&key=second`. In those cases, deepEquals will
>   require all the values (in any order) to match. All other predicates
>   will match if any value matches, so an equals predicate will match
>   with the value of `second` in the example above.

So I can just remove the changeable query string value from the predicate, or I can keep it in there, it doesn't matter.

```
  {
     "equals":{
        "method":"GET",
        "path":"/sword/eBISXMLInvoice2.do",
        "query": {
          "action": "index"
        }
     }
  }
```